# AWS Cloudfront RTMP Playback Speed

Tags: video, amazon-web-services, jwplayer, amazon-cloudfront, rtmp

I'm using Amazon Cloudfront RTMP and JWPlayer to stream videos on my e-learning system. My students asked me about whether I can allow to manage video playback speed, to play video x2 or x4 faster, like Lynda does.

I know it's possible in HTML5 but I have to use flash player and RTMP protocol.
Is it possible to provide playback speed function in JWPlayer with AWS RTMP.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to change the actual framerate or playback speed in Flash.

I have a bit of a hack that does this, but it only works for Slow Motion, and it simulates slow motion by pressing play/pause over and over again, but again, this only works for slow motion, not 2x speed or 4x speed.

Here is the information - http://www.pluginsbyethan.com/slowmo6.html

The source is available, you can always modify the plugin to make it seek ahead every second, to simulate fast forward, instead of the play/pause toggle I am doing here.

However, if you use HTML5, this is already possible, see here - https://github.com/emaxsaun/speed/

Comment: Thanks but, unfortunately I need speed up not speed down. Is this something that you have in your feature list? Are you going to implement it?

Comment: It's a limitation of Flash. JW Player can't change Flash.

Comment: Yeah, we can't change the framerate of the video. Like I said above, you can always modify my source of the AS3 version to make it seek ahead a few seconds every seconds, instead of making it play/pause, to simulate fast forward, instead of slow motion.